# Why strings should be hardcoded when using sharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, optimization

I have heard that using `editor.putString("Message","Hello");` is bad practice, and you should instead do `editor.putString(getString(R.string.messagestring),"Hello");`. But why? It is longer and has the same result, and looks more messy imo. Is it because it's harder to make a typo?

Here is an example from Signal:
[Source](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/f9adb4e4554a44fd65b77320e34bf4bccf7924ce/src/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/DatabaseUpgradeActivity.java#L267/)

```
  if (params[0] < SCREENSHOTS) {
    boolean screenSecurity = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(TextSecurePreferences.SCREEN_SECURITY_PREF, true);
    TextSecurePreferences.setScreenSecurityEnabled(getApplicationContext(), screenSecurity);
  }
```

Comment: Hey @WorkyNob, I suggest you provide a code example with both options to make your use case more explicit.

Comment: Seems odd to have keys from resources. Where exactly have you heard such advice? Maybe there's some context missing in the question.

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani  Here you go, edited!

Comment: @laalto Here you go, edited!

Comment: Note that this example you edited does not have the SP key from resources. It seems to have a `static final String` constant such as `TextSecurePreferences.SCREEN_SECURITY_PREF` for the key. That makes sense.

Comment: If you are happy with one of the answers, please mark it as accepted. You find the explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/tour and here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 2):

`String` values in code for human readable text are bad.

Doing so makes localization impossible.

Values from `R.string.` on the other hand automagically use the right language (given that you use `values`, `values-es`, `values-fr`, ... and put translations)

Note: You should probably not translate the `key` of a `SharedPreference` but the value (`"Hello"`) part since that's presumably the human readable thing.

```
editor.putString("message", getString(R.string.messagestring));
```

The key could change if the user changes device language which means the old stored value will no longer be found under the new key. If you want keys in a central place it's a good idea to have them defined as `static final` constants in code.

```
editor.putString(MyPrefConstants.PREF_MESSAGE, getString(R.string.messagestring));
```

I would actually consider using keys that come from `R.string` a very questionable design decision.  This applies to anything that is intended to be machine-consumed rather than visible text to the user. There are a few exceptions but they are rare.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this is an answer to the question.

Comment: @laalto I just guessed the intention wasn't to use the key from resources but the value.

Comment: @laalto I think it definitely answers the question of *why* to use `R.string.xxx`, and answer is: Localization. --- This answer then goes further and addresses the mistake of using `R.string.xxx` on the *key*, when it is the *value* that should be localized.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, seems like this answer has now been edited to answer a plausible interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about maintenance, reusability, cleanness and if needed easier localization.  
 Take for example `"Message"`.  
How many times would you use this string in your code if it is the key for Preferences? More than 1, right? Imagine that you write over and over "Message". Isn't it possible to misspell it at least once? Well you can't misspell a string resource, because the compiler won't let you.  
Another thing: you know where all your UI strings are so you know where to look when you need to change 1 of them and once you do it is changed throughout the app.

 Finally if you want your up to be multilingual this is the only way with the Editor provided by AS.  
 
**Edit:** As for the question if strings like keys for `Preferences` should be in the `Resources` my answer is **yes**. It's up to the programmer to give proper ids to the string resources so to distinguish the UI items from the in-app items.

Answer (score 0):

It's **Not Necessary** but **Good Practice**.

eg.

`editor.putString("Message","Hello");`
here the key -> "Message"
it is possible that sometimes you make a TYPING ERROR or SPELLING MISTAKE of writing "Message" to "Massage" or something else.

to avoid these type of situations, we should write in this way 
`editor.putString(getString(R.string.messagestring),"Hello");`